# Defining absolute margin in nested div

Tags: html, css

I hope I described it correctly when I stated "nested div".

I have an image in a div like this:

```
content -> content-inner -> column_left
```

I'm unable to make the image begin at 0 px (the very left side of the screen).
It seems I'm trapped in margin definition of the div.

The divs are defined like this (seen in Chrome Inspector):

[image]

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 280px;
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#content-inner {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.column_left {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 65%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    float: left;
}
```

I created a new div like this:

```
.inlineimage 
{
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 3px;
}
```

And then I assigned it to the image within the "column-left" div:

```
<div class="inlineimage">
    <img src="images/myimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

However, the image sticks to the border of the column (which is around 105 px).

How could I make the image stick to 0 px margin from the left side of the page?

Thank you.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: @Rob Thank you.

Comment: Why not remove "max-width: 980px;" rule of #content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position your `.inlineimage` container to `position: relative;` then position the `img` as

```
.inlineimage > img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

This way your image sticks to the top/left

Comment: thank you for that @tmighty hope it'll help take care

Comment: I noticed I do need your approach! However, the image isn't aligned left. I would have needed it centered on the screen. When I try this using .inlineimage > img {
  position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
text-align:center; 
width:100%;
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
... the image overlaps text and is also not centered.

Comment: Isn't it already centered without the absolute positioning? I don't get what you're trying to achieve there